# Poor Use Case of Object.assign() - Simple Example

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I'm reading the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) on `Object.assign()` and came across one phrase that I don't understand:

> The Object.assign() method only copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object. It uses [[Get]] on the source and [[Set]] on the target, so it will invoke getters and setters. Therefore it assigns properties versus just copying or defining new properties. This may make it unsuitable for merging new properties into a prototype if the merge sources contain getters. For copying property definitions, including their enumerability, into prototypes Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor() and Object.defineProperty() should be used instead.

Particularly this line:

> This may make it unsuitable for merging new properties into a prototype if the merge sources contain getters.

I'm not exactly sure what a good example is for advocating against using `Object.assign`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A *getter* is an accessor function for a property that returns the property's value. This is what an object with a getter looks like:

```js
const obj = {
    get example() {
        console.log("getter was called");
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    }
};
console.log(obj.example);
// Note no () ---------^
```

Notice that when we read the value of the `example` property, the function gets run even though it doesn't look like a function call.

What that part of the MDN docs is saying is that `Object.assign` will *call* that getter, it won't create an equivalent getter on the target object. So:

```js
const obj = {
    get example() {
        console.log("getter was called");
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    }
};
const obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj); // calls getter
console.log(obj2.example);           // just has a simple value
console.log(obj2.example);           // same value, no call
console.log(obj2.example);           // same value, no call
```

`obj`'s `example` property has a getter, but `obj2`'s `example` property is just a simple value property. `Object.assign` didn't copy the getter, it just grabbed the getter's current value and assigned it ot `obj2.example`.

You *can* copy getters, just not with `Object.assign`:

```js
function copyProperties(target, source) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source).forEach(name => {
        Object.defineProperty(
            target,
            name,
            Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, name)
        );
    });
    return target;
}
const obj = {
    get example() {
        console.log("getter was called");
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    }
};
const obj2 = copyProperties({}, obj); // calls getter
console.log(obj2.example);            // calls getter
console.log(obj2.example);            // calls getter
console.log(obj2.example);            // calls getter
```

Of course, if the getter isn't designed to be copied between objects (for instance, if `example`'s getter explicitly used `obj`), you may get unexpected results.

Comment: This makes so much sense, thank you. But what if I've added specific non-enumerable properties to `source` object and I'm using your last example with `getOwnPropertyNames`? Even those we're using this method to get the non-enumerable getters and setters, it'll also pick up any other non-enumerables (such as `length` if it's an array object). So I'd have to exclude them manually in the custom `copyProperties` method, yes?

Comment: @qarthandso: I just used `getOwnPropertyNames` almost at random, figuring if someone wanted to copy getters and setters and such, they probably would want to copy non-enumerable properties as well. (By that logic,I probably should have included `getOwnPropertySymbols`, too; but it was just a small example.) If you want to copy properties but stick to enumerable ones, use `Object.keys` which only gives you own, enumerable properties.

Comment: Gosh, @Mark, thanks! :-)